# Can the coefficients of an elliptic curve be recovered from the curve itself?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials, elliptic-curves

Let $K$ denote an algebraically closed field. Suppose $E$ and $E'$ are elliptic curves given by Weierstrass equations with parameters $(a_1,a_3,a_2,a_4,a_6)$ and $(a_1',a_3',a_2',a_4',a_6').$ From $E = E'$ as subsets of projective space, can we deduce that $a_i = a'_i$?

Comment: You are assuming that the curves are embedded in the plane via the given Weierstrass equations? If so, the answer is yes. Since $E=E'$, their defining polynomials (as subvarieties of the projective plane) are scalar multiples of each other. Since these polynomials are Weierstrass equations, the normalization condition forces them to be equal.

Comment: However, an "abstract" elliptic curve can correspond to more than one set of Weierstrass parameters.